# How does CSS handle image manipulations internally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-processing

In general, to perform any image manipulations, an Image Processing or Computer Vision library is used. OpenCV, PIL etc are some of them.

How does CSS perform image manipulations internally?

Does it use any existing library for doing it?
If yes, what is the library and where can I find it?

Consider following sample code snippet :

```
div:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

How can I see the source code of **scale()** in above code?
Which library is used for performing scaling?

As implementation of CSS is browser-dependent, how **BROWSER** does it?

Comment: The implementation of CSS is browser-dependent, so it's not "how css does that", but "how $BROWSER" does that.

Comment: check the source of browser, almost all them are open source ;) the you will that it's like OpenCV and any other software ... at the end a browser is a software written with a langague and running on your PC

Comment: Good but very broad question and no standard answer can be provided as different browsers will have some variations and their own "optimizations" on how they implement transforms. Moreover answer would be in implementation specific language (C++/Pascal etc) and not those tagged above. Therefore I vote to close the above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scale` results in a [`<transform-function>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function)

A transform function essentially uses [this specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-property)

Which links to this [transform rendering specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-rendering)

Most big browsers will likely use this as their guideline.

[Here's the source code for the `ScaleTransformOperation` in WebKit](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/f18e79d901f56154f80eea1e2218544285e62623/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/transforms/ScaleTransformOperation.cpp)